# Grails sImple chat - Chat messages not displaying on screen

Tags: grails

Following is a code fragment obtained from [Grails website](http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-simple-ajax-chat/).

```
<script>
    function messageKeyPress(field,event) {
        var theCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
        var message = $('#messageBox').val();
        if (theCode == 13){
            <g:remoteFunction action="submitMessage" params="\'message=\'+message" update="temp"/>
            $('#messageBox').val('');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function retrieveLatestMessages() {
        <g:remoteFunction action="retrieveLatestMessages" update="chatMessages"/>
    }
    function pollMessages() {
        retrieveLatestMessages();
        setTimeout('pollMessages()', 5000);
    }
    pollMessages();
</script>
```

The above code worked but when i added the `Controller` it stopped working. I meant that the records gets saved in the DB, but i am not able to retrieve the data and display on screen.

This is what i did

```
        <g:remoteFunction controller="message" action="retrieveLatestMessages" update="chatMessages"/>
```

The `MessageController` function is as follows:

```
@Secured([ 'ROLE_USER'])
    def retrieveLatestMessages() {
        println "test"
        def messages = Message.listOrderByDate(order: 'desc', max:1000)
        [messages:messages.reverse()]

        println messages


   }
```

The above controller function gets executed (I see the `println` statements on console), but the data isn't getting populating on the screen.

Can someone help me out here

**UPDATE**

> [{"class":"myPro.Message","id":3,"date":"2014-07-23T17:31:58Z","message":"dfdf","name":"hi"},{"class":"myPro.Message","id":2,"date":"2014-07-23T17:31:56Z","message":"dfdfdf","name":"dd"},{"class":"myPro.Message","id":1,"date":"2014-07-23T17:31:18Z","message":"xxxx","name":"fie"}]

Answer (score 0):

Your method - `retrieveLatestMessages()` action in your case - must return a `model`, but it returns the output of `println` instead.

To make your code work, you must place the `model` in the last line, or explicitly return it by using `return` statement:

```
def retrieveLatestMessages() {
    println "test"
    def messages = Message.listOrderByDate(order: 'desc', max:1000)
    println messages
    [messages:messages.reverse()]
}
```

Comment: I have this setup but nothing gets displayed on the view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import grails.converters.JSON

@Secured([ 'ROLE_USER'])
def retrieveLatestMessages() {
    println "test"
    def messages = Message.listOrderByDate(order: 'asc', max:1000)
    render messages as JSON
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: I have also added the JSON that i get, but it doesn't get displayed on the screen. I have posted my JSON string on the Post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this sample app working on mine with no issues but here is the thing, this process requires you to poll the page consistently and it is resource intensive:

I ended up writing a domainClass that was bound to a Datasource that was using the HQL db and was outside of my own app, the process requires a DB table to stream chat....

Alternative is to move away from polling and use websockets:

check out this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QBdUcFqRkU

Then check out this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BikL52HYaZg

Finally look at this :

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-websocket-example

This has been updated and includes the 2nd method of using winsocket to make simple chat ....